# Python: Size limitations on writing to a file

Tags: python, file

Is there a hard or upper limit on writing to a file in python? I have a CSV with about 8 million records, and my script randomizes the rows then outputs it. When it completes, the randomized file only has about 5 million records. Any idea what could be happening, or if there is in fact a limit I should be aware of?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the code I use to write the file.

```
def createOutputFile(fileIn, header, fileCap, extension):

outfileName = 'Randomized_Data.'+extension

if(header == 'Y' or header == 'y'):
    infile = open(fileIn,'r')
    headerline = infile.readline()

    lines = open(fileIn).readlines()    # read whole file
    random.shuffle(lines)               # randomize
    lines = lines[:fileCap]             # write up to the use specified length
    with open(outfileName,'a+') as outfile:
        if(not headerline==""):
            outfile.write(headerline)
        outfile.writelines(lines)
```

EDIT 2: A question about the `fileCap` variable, this will be the maximum length of the file.

```
if (fc == ""):
            # gets size of file (in rows)
            file = open(fn)
            fc = len(file.readlines())
        else:
            fc = int(fc)
```

where `fc` is passed as `fileCap`

Comment: Show us your code :)

Comment: There is no limit, without the code there is nothing else we can do.

Comment: The limit is your disk size, or the maximum file size that your filesystem supports. But the program should alert you if it can't write to a file. This sounds like a logic error; as Andrea says, show us your code.

Comment: Updated OP with some code :)

Comment: What is the value of `fileCap`?

Comment: sorry, fileCap will be the entire length of the file. I will update OP with that as well.

Comment: You limit the size here: `lines = lines[:fileCap]`.

Comment: `lines = lines[:fileCap]             # write up to the use specified length` truncates the length of output file, I would bet, that `fileCap` is those 5 million you mentioned

Comment: As an aside, `del lines[fileCap:]` trims the list in place which is likely a bit faster on large lists.

Comment: What's the point of using `lines[:fileCap]` if `fileCap` is the length of `lines`? (Well, *in theory* it should be the length of `lines`, in practice it's not, as you are seeing.)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini the script allows for the entire amount of data to be randomized, or a user-defined amount of randomized data.

Comment: How about verifying that `fileCap` is what you think it is in your test. Temporarily add `assert len(lines) == fileCap` and see if it is true.

Comment: @tdelaney `del lines[fileCap:]` will, internally and in the reference implementation, have to zero out every pointer past the specified index, decrease their reference counts, and update the internal element count. Making a new list will require allocating the memory, setting the initial element count, setting pointers, and increasing reference counts (and then decreasing again if/when the old list is destroyed). So I guess it depends on what % of the list is being deleted :)

Comment: @tdelaney I just ran it again and printed the length of `fileCap` and it was incorrect, compared to the amount of records in the file I was reading from.

Comment: I'm puzzled by why you're testing (fc == ""), when you're about to use fc as an integer. It may be ok, but why's the "if" there at all? If fc wasn't around before you'd get a NameError; so it was apparently used before. Could it still have an old value in it like 5000000?

Comment: @TextGeek if fc == "", it will use the entire length of the file, i.e., should be using the 8m records. if it's not blank, it will use whatever the user has defined.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `del lines[fileCap:]` will win every time because any cost it has in removing members is less that the cost of the original list loosing all of its members plus building the new list. Even when favoring the alternate case,  `timeit('del lines[1:]', setup='lines=list(range(10000))')` ran for me in `0.202` while `timeit('lines=lines[:1]', setup='lines=list(range(100))')` took
`0.359`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't something in my Python code, actually seemed to be a bad character in the file.